# Successive nearest neighbors in R

Tags: r

I have n data points in a data frame that includes X and Y coordinates. I'd like to take any point (hereafter the first point), find its nearest neighbor (i.e. the second point), then find the nearest point from the second point (i.e. the third point) other than the first point, then find the nearest neighbor from the third point other than the first and second points, and so on. And I'd like to add two columns to the data frame: one column containing numbers (1 for the first point, 2 for the second point and so on) and the other column containing distance values such that each point has a value that is distance to the next nearest point identified through the rule explained above. I wonder whether there is a package or a minimal set of R codes that does this.

Example data:

```
structure(list(sanimusho = 1:10, Latitude = c(41.84752, 41.84665, 41.84478, 41.84365, 41.84683, 41.84856, 41.84653, 41.8452, 41.8457, 41.84446), Longitude = c(44.98355, 44.98944, 45.04445, 45.04428, 45.04112, 45.03329, 45.03202, 45.02737, 45.01077, 45.01041),     Altitude = c(1435L, 1455L, 1545L, 1509L, 1588L, 1668L, 1574L,     1556L, 1479L, 1446L), fartobi = c(18.4, 19.8, 18.6, 18.4,     18.2, 18.2, 18.4, 19.4, 18.4, 18.2), X = c(498634.403, 499123.349,     503690.176, 503676.128, 503413.615, 502763.526, 502658.183,     502272.204, 500894.097, 500864.228), Y = c(4632846.902, 4632750.232,     4632543.515, 4632418.048, 4632770.98, 4632962.773, 4632737.351,     4632589.553, 4632644.76, 4632507.084)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

Comment: Can you provide some example data?

Comment: sanimusho,Latitude,Longitude,Altitude,fartobi,X,Y
1,41.84752,44.98355,1435,18.4,498634.403,4632846.902
2,41.84665,44.98944,1455,19.8,499123.349,4632750.232
3,41.84478,45.04445,1545,18.6,503690.176,4632543.515
4,41.84365,45.04428,1509,18.4,503676.128,4632418.048
5,41.84683,45.04112,1588,18.2,503413.615,4632770.98
6,41.84856,45.03329,1668,18.2,502763.526,4632962.773
7,41.84653,45.03202,1574,18.4,502658.183,4632737.351
8,41.8452,45.02737,1556,19.4,502272.204,4632589.553
9,41.8457,45.01077,1479,18.4,500894.097,4632644.76
10,41.84446,45.01041,1446,18.2,500864.228,4632507.084

Comment: @Lexo that's not how you should provide data. Use ```dput``` on a sample on your data to generate the code necessary to replicate your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and looping that works for the sample data. I leave it as an exercise to reverse engineer it.

```
library(dplyr)

# df <- my_sample_data
first_point <- 1

neighbors_df <- tibble(sanimusho = numeric(), sanimusho_nb = numeric())

for(i in seq(nrow(df))) {
  next_neighbor <- df %>%
    filter(sanimusho == tail(c(first_point, neighbors_df$sanimusho_nb), 1)) %>%
    merge(select(df, sanimusho_nb = sanimusho, X_nb = X, Y_nb = Y)) %>%
    mutate(dist_nb = sqrt((X - X_nb) ^ 2 + (Y - Y_nb) ^ 2)) %>%
    filter(sanimusho != sanimusho_nb, !(sanimusho_nb %in% neighbors_df$sanimusho)) %>%
    top_n(-1, dist_nb + row_number()) %>%
    select(-X_nb, -Y_nb)

  if (nrow(next_neighbor) > 0) {
    neighbors_df <- bind_rows(neighbors_df, next_neighbor)
  } else {
    neighbors_df <- bind_rows(neighbors_df, filter(df, sanimusho == tail(neighbors_df$sanimusho_nb, 1)))
    break
  }
}
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 10 x 9
   sanimusho sanimusho_nb Latitude Longitude Altitude fartobi       X        Y dist_nb
       <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <int>   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>
 1         1            2     41.8      45.0     1435    18.4 498634. 4632847.    498.
 2         2           10     41.8      45.0     1455    19.8 499123. 4632750.   1758.
 3        10            9     41.8      45.0     1446    18.2 500864. 4632507.    141.
 4         9            8     41.8      45.0     1479    18.4 500894. 4632645.   1379.
 5         8            7     41.8      45.0     1556    19.4 502272. 4632590.    413.
 6         7            6     41.8      45.0     1574    18.4 502658. 4632737.    249.
 7         6            5     41.8      45.0     1668    18.2 502764. 4632963.    678.
 8         5            3     41.8      45.0     1588    18.2 503414. 4632771.    358.
 9         3            4     41.8      45.0     1545    18.6 503690. 4632544.    126.
10         4           NA     41.8      45.0     1509    18.4 503676. 4632418.     NA
```